# Как распознать текст с фрагмента экрана?

Tags: python

Как можно реализовать, чтобы в реальном времени(раз в 2 секунды) считывалась информация с монитора ? Вот пример фрагмента экрана с которого надо считать информацию и занести в переменную [image: фрагмент экрана]

Comment: Вопрос чрезвычайно неконкретный.  В питоне нет понятия "экран". Есть окна, виджеты...  Это в режиме GUI. Если говорить о консольном режиме, то там всё по другому.  Непонятно - речь идёт об одном приложении или о двух разных.

Ваш вопрос - он о чём?

Comment: @sergey есть приложение, в приложении в определённом месте выводятся эти координаты. Нужно их считать и записать переменную

Comment: Т.е. всё-таки **два**  приложения? Пишет на "экран" одно, а читать будет другое? А ОС какая - в винде и люнихе работа с "экраном" выполняется совершенно по разному.  Первое приложение - GUI или консольное? Здесь тоже абсолютно разные подходы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам может помочь [pytesseract](https://pypi.org/project/pytesseract/).

А захватить экран можно при помощи [MSS](https://pypi.org/project/mss/).

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).